# How to generate subset in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table letter. One column called 'letter', type is VARCHAR. 
For example

```
---------
|letter|
|a     |
|b     |
|c     |
--------
```

And the output I want is:

```
-----------------
|NULL|NULL|NULL|
|a   |NULL|NULL|
|b   |NULL|NULL|
|c   |NULL|NULL|
|a   |b   |NULL|
|a   |c   |NULL|
|b   |c   |NULL|
|a   |b   |c   |
-----------------
```

How to generate the table like that....

Comment: In addition to showing no code, you also left out the actual logic which generates the output.  Please include more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE letters (letter char);
INSERT INTO letters VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO letters VALUES ('b');
INSERT INTO letters VALUES ('c');

SELECT
   t1.letter,
   t2.letter,
   t3.letter
 FROM 
   (SELECT NULL AS letter UNION SELECT letter FROM letters) t1
   JOIN (SELECT NULL AS letter UNION SELECT letter FROM letters) t2 ON t2.LETTER IS NULL OR t2.letter > t1.letter
   JOIN (SELECT NULL AS letter UNION SELECT letter FROM letters) t3 ON t3.LETTER IS NULL OR t3.letter > t2.letter
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8232b9/2